# What should be the datatype of the tokens a lexer returns to its parser?

Tags: data-types, lexer, flex

As said in the title, which data type should a lexer return/give the parser? When reading the [lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) article that Wikipedia has, it stated that:

> In computer science, lexical analysis is the process of converting a sequence of characters (such as in a computer program or web page) into a sequence of tokens (**strings** with an identified "meaning").

However, in complete contradiction to the above statement, When another question I asked on a different site([Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138402/creating-a-simple-interpreter-for-the-quartz-language) if you are curious) was answered, The person answering stated that:

> The lexer usually reads the **string** and converts this into a stream ... of lexemes. The lexemes only need to be a stream of **numbers**.

and he gave this visual:

```
nl_output => 256
output    => 257
<string>  => 258
```

Later on in the article He mentioned `Flex`, a already existing lexer, and said writing 'rules' with it would be simpler than writing a lexer by hand. He proceeded to give me this example:

```
Space              [ \r\n\t]
QuotedString       "[^"]*"
%%
nl_output          {return 256;}
output             {return 257;}
{QuotedString}     {return 258;}
{Space}            {/* Ignore */}
.                  {error("Unmatched character");}
%%
```

To further my insight and get more information, I read the Wikipedia article about [Flex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_(lexical_analyser_generator)). the Flex article showed that you could define a set of syntax rules, with tokens, in the following way:

```
digit         [0-9]
letter        [a-zA-Z]

%%
"+"                  { return PLUS;       }
"-"                  { return MINUS;      }
"*"                  { return TIMES;      }
"/"                  { return SLASH;      }
"("                  { return LPAREN;     }
")"                  { return RPAREN;     }
";"                  { return SEMICOLON;  }
","                  { return COMMA;      }
"."                  { return PERIOD;     }
":="                 { return BECOMES;    }
"="                  { return EQL;        }
"<>"                 { return NEQ;        }
"<"                  { return LSS;        }
">"                  { return GTR;        }
"<="                 { return LEQ;        }
">="                 { return GEQ;        }
"begin"              { return BEGINSYM;   }
"call"               { return CALLSYM;    }
"const"              { return CONSTSYM;   }
"do"                 { return DOSYM;      }
"end"                { return ENDSYM;     }
"if"                 { return IFSYM;      }
"odd"                { return ODDSYM;     }
"procedure"          { return PROCSYM;    }
"then"               { return THENSYM;    }
"var"                { return VARSYM;     }
"while"              { return WHILESYM;   }
```

It seems to me that the Flex lexer is returning strings of keywords\tokens. But It could be returning constants that are equal to certain numbers.

If the lexer was going to return numbers, how would it read string literals? returning a number is fine for single keywords, But how would you deal with a string? Wouldn't the lexer have to convert the string to binary numbers and then the parser would convert the numbers back to a string. It seems much more logical(and easier) for the lexer to return strings, and then let the parser convert any number string literals into actual numbers.

Or could the lexer possible return both? I've been trying to write a simple lexer in c++, which lets you have only **one** return type for your functions. Thus leading me to ask my question.

To condense my question into a paragraph: When writing a lexer, and assuming that it could only return **one** data type(strings or numbers), which would be the more logical choice?

Comment: The lexer returns what you tell it to return.  If your design calls for numbers, then it will return numbers.  Obviously, representing string literals is going to require a bit more than that.  See also [Is it a Lexer's Job to Parse Numbers and Strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6320132/102937)  Note that string literals are not generally considered "Language Elements."

Comment: @RobertHarvey So would you convert the string literal into binary numbers?.

Comment: As I understand it, the purpose of the lexer is to take the language elements (like keywords, operators and so forth) and turn them into tokens.  As such, quoted strings are of no interest to the lexer, because they are not language elements.  Though I've never written a lexer myself, I would imagine that the quoted string is simply passed through unchanged (including the quotes).

Comment: So, what your saying is that the lexer does not read or care about string literals. And so the parser must look for these string literals? This is very confusing.

Comment: You might want to spend a few minutes reading this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis

Comment: @RobertHarvey The purpose of a lexer is to take raw source text and turn it into a series of tokens representing language elements.  (The difference is subtle, but real.)  As Telastyn points out below, the token generally is a small struct or object that holds basic data including Token Type, Location, and Raw Text, in one form or another.  (Location is important; it's how the compiler reports the position of errors in the code, by reading the location of the token--or of the AST node derived from the token, which got its location from the token--where the error occurred.)

Comment: @MasonWheeler: Sure, I get that.  Does that mean the Tokenizer must provide room for a string in each token, even if there isn't one 95 percent of the time?

Comment: @RobertHarvey There are various ways to do it.  Having a string reference as part of the token struct is one way.  A second way is to have a second Location member which points to the end of the source stream, and then if the parser needs to get the raw string it can get it by copying from the beginning to the end.  (The first way has the advantage of not needing to make the raw source text available to the parser, which makes it a more popular way to do it IME.)  Bear in mind that parsers and lexers tend to be heavily optimized for *speed*; a bit of extra memory isn't a problem here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally, if you're processing a language though lexing and parsing, you've got a definition of your lexical tokens, e.g.:

```
NUMBER ::= [0-9]+
ID     ::= [a-Z]+, except for keywords
IF     ::= 'if'
LPAREN ::= '('
RPAREN ::= ')'
COMMA  ::= ','
LBRACE ::= '{'
RBRACE ::= '}'
SEMICOLON ::= ';'
...
```

and you have a grammar for the parser:

```
STATEMENT ::= IF LPAREN EXPR RPAREN STATEMENT
            | LBRACE STATEMENT RBRACE
            | EXPR SEMICOLON
EXPR      ::= ID
            | NUMBER
            | ID LPAREN EXPRS RPAREN
...
```

Your lexer takes the input stream and produces a stream of tokens.  The stream of tokens is consumed by the parser to produce a parse tree.  In some cases, just knowing the *type* of the token is enough (e.g, LPAREN, RBRACE, FOR), but in some cases, you'll need the actual *value* that is associated with the token.  For instance, when you encounter an ID token, you'll want the actual characters that make up the ID later on when you're trying to figure out what identifier you're trying to reference.

So, you typically have something more or less like this:

```
enum TokenType {
  NUMBER, ID, IF, LPAREN, RPAREN, ...;
}

class Token {
  TokenType type;
  String value;
}
```

So when the lexer returns a token, you know what type it is (which you need for the parsing), and the sequence of characters that it was generated from (which you'll need later on to interpret string and numeric literals, identifiers, etc.).  It might feel like you're returning two values, since you're returning a very simple aggregate type, but you really do need both parts. After all, you'd want to treat the following programs differently:

```
if (2 > 0) {
  print("2 > 0");
}
```

```
if (0 > 2) {
  print("0 > 2");
}
```

These produce the same sequence of token *types*: IF, LPAREN, NUMBER, GREATER_THAN, NUMBER, RPAREN, LBRACE, ID, LPAREN, STRING, RPAREN, SEMICOLON, RBRACE.  That means they *parse* the same, too.  But when you're actually doing something with the parse tree, you'll care that the value of the first number is '2' (or '0') and that the value of the second number is '0' (or '2'), and that the value of the string is '2 > 0' (or '0 > 2').

Comment: I get most of what your saying, but **how** is that `String value` going to get filled? will it be filled with a string or a number? And also, how would i define the `String` type?

Comment: @Mr.Python In the simplest case, it's just the string of characters that matched the lexical production.  So, if you see **foo(23, "bar")**, you'd get the tokens **[ID,"foo"], [LPAREN,"("], [NUMBER,"23"], [COMMA,","], [STRING,""23""], [RPAREN,")"]**.  Preserving that information could be important.  Or you could take another approach and have the value have a union type that can be a string, or a number, etc., and pick the right value type based on what kind of token type you have (e.g., when token type is NUMBER, use value.num, and when it's STRING, use value.str).

Comment: @MrPython **"And also, how would i define the String type?"** I was writing from a Java-ish mindset.  If you're working in C++ you could use C++'s string type, or if you're working in C, you could use a char*.  The point is that associated with a token, you have the corresponding value, or the text that you can interpret to produce the value.

Comment: @Mr.Python The parser should generally only be parsing based on the *types* of the tokens that it is receiving, but it should generally be preserving the *values* of the tokens that it receives for subsequent analysis.  Where exactly you determine that "this sequence of characters should be interpreted as this number" varies.  You could do it relatively early, or you could do it later.  That's probably up to you.  In some languages, it's easy to have a very simple lexical analysis, and a subsequent step for figuring out some things about each token.  E.g., in one Lisp-like parser I wrote, I...

Comment: @Mr.Python ...simply lexed out LPAREN as (, RPAREN as ), and ID as a sequence of any non-space, non-(, non-) character. That made lexing and parsing easy, and it was a later phase that made a distinction between [ID,"foo"] (a symbol) and [ID,"23"] (a number), basically by trial and error (can I parse it as a number?  OK, then it's a number;  or not, then it's a symbol).

Comment: I  think if the Lexer try to return an TokenID "LPAREN", then the string value "(" is not necessary, because we know it must be "(". So in this case, we don't need to set the string field of the Token class.

Comment: @ollydbg23 that's an option, and not an unreasonable one, but it makes the system less internally consistent. E.g., if you want the string value of the last town you parsed,you'd now have to explicitly check for a null value and then use a reverse token- to- string lookup to find out what the string would have been.  Plus, it's tighter coupling between the lexer and the parser; there's be more code to update if LPAREN could ever match different or multiple strings.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I agree with you, if the lexeme string is empty for the Token with ID "LPAREN", a token-id to string lookup is need(this is usually for debugging or logging for the Lexer I think). BTW: I don't think a LPAREN matches different strings, as mostly it stands for "(".

Comment: @ollydbg23 One case would be a simple pseudo-minifier.  It's easy enough to do `parse(inputStream).forEach(token -> print(token.string); print(' '))` (i.e., just print the string values of the tokens, separated by space). That's pretty quick.  And even if LPAREN can only come about from "(", that could be a constant string in memory, so including a reference to it in the token might be no more expensive than including the null reference.  In general, I'd rather write code that doesn't make me special case any code.

Answer (score 8):

> As said in the title, which data type should a lexer return/give the parser?

"Token", obviously. A lexer produces a stream of tokens, so it should return a stream of *tokens*.

> He mentioned Flex, a already existing lexer, and said writing 'rules' with it would be simpler than writing a lexer by hand.

Machine-generated lexers have the advantage that you can generate them quickly, which is particularly handy if you think your lexical grammar is going to change a lot.  They have the disadvantage that you often don't get a lot of flexibility in your implementation choices.

That said, who cares if it is "simpler"?  Writing the lexer usually isn't the hard part!

> When writing a lexer, and assuming that it could only return one data type(strings or numbers), which would be the more logical choice?

Neither.  A lexer typically has a "next" operation that returns a token, so it should return **a token**. A token is not a string or a number. It's a token.

The last lexer I wrote was a "full fidelity" lexer, meaning that it returned a token that tracked the location of all whitespace and comments -- which we call "trivia" -- in the program, as well as the token.  In my lexer a token was defined as:

- An array of leading trivia
- A token kind
- A token width in characters
- An array of trailing trivia

Trivia was defined as:

- A trivia kind -- whitespace, newline, comment, and so on
- A trivia width in characters

So if we had something like

```
    foo + /* comment */
/* another comment */ bar;
```

that would lex as four tokens with token kinds `Identifier`, `Plus`, `Identifier`, `Semicolon`, and widths 3, 1, 3, 1.  The first identifier has leading trivia consisting of `Whitespace` with a width of 4 and trailing trivia `Whitespace` with width of 1.  The `Plus` has no leading trivia and trailing trivia consisting of one whitespace, a comment and a newline.  The final identifier has a leading trivia of a comment and a space, and so on.

With this scheme every character in the file gets accounted for in the output of the lexer, which is a handy property to have for things like syntax coloring.

Of course, if you don't need the trivia then you can simply make a token two things: the kind and the width.

You might notice that the token and trivia contain only their widths, not their absolute position in the source code. That's deliberate.  Such a scheme has advantages:

- It is compact in memory and wire format
- It enables re-lexing upon edits; this is useful if the lexer is running inside an IDE. That is, if you detect an edit in a token, you just back up your lexer to a couple tokens before the edit and start lexing again until you're sync'ed with the previous token stream.  When you type a character the *position* of every token after that character changes, but usually only one or two tokens change in width, so you can re-use all that state.
- The exact character offsets of every token can easily be derived by iterating over the token stream and keeping track of the current offset. Once you have the exact character offsets then it is easy to extract the text when necessary.

If you don't care about any of those scenarios, then a token could be represented as a kind and an offset, rather than a kind and a width.

But the key takeaway here is: **programming is the art of making useful abstractions**.  You are manipulating tokens, so make a useful abstraction over tokens, and then you get to choose for yourself what implementation details underlie it.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you return a small structure which has a number signifying the token (or enum value for ease of use) and an optional value (string, or possibly generic/templated value). Another approach would be to return a derived type for elements that need to carry extra data. Both are mildly distasteful, but fine enough solutions to a practical problem.

Comment: What do you mean by _mildly distasteful_? Are they inefficient ways of getting string values?

Comment: @Mr.Python - they'll lead to a lot of checks before use in code, which is inefficient, but moreso makes the code a little more complex/fragile.

Comment: I have a similar question when designing a lexer in C++, I could return a `Token *` or a simply a `Token`, or a `TokenPtr` which is a shared pointer of `Token` class. But I also see some lexer return just a TokenType, and store the string or number value in other global or static variables. Another question is the how can we store the Location information, do I need to have a Token struct which have TokenType, String, and Location fields? Thanks.

Comment: @ollydbg23 - any of these things can work. I would use a struct. And for non-learning languages you'll be using a parser generator anyways.

Comment: @Telastyn thanks for the reply. You mean a Token struct could be something like `struct Token {TokenType id; std::string lexeme; int line; int column;}`, right?  For a public function of Lexer, such as `PeekToken()`, the function could return a `Token *` or `TokenPtr`. I think it for a while, if the function just return the TokenType, how does the Parser try to get the other information about the Token? So, a pointer like datatype is preferred for return from such function. Any comments about my idea? Thanks